# Select the optimal edge to add to a subgraph for minimal the shortest path

Tags: shortest-path

The question is as follows:
Let G be connected, directed weighted Graph with non-negative edge weights and let s and t be vertices in G. Furthermore, let K be a subgraph of G with the same number of vertices but fewer edges.

The task is to add an edge that is in G but not in K such that the length of the shortest path between s and t is as small as possible with a constraint of O(|E|*log|V|).

Answer (score 1):

Create two copies of $K$, and denote them by $K_1, K_2$. for a vertex $v$,we will denote by $v_1$ its copy in $K_1$ and by $v_2$ its copy in $K_2$.

Now, for each edge $e=(v,u)$ in $G$, add a (directed) edge between $v_1\in K_1$ and $u_2\in K_2$.

Now search for the smallest path between $s_1$ and $t_2$.

---

As a side note, the "trick" of cloning graphs and connecting them in a particular way is very useful in algorithms.